# Problem with phpStan error : __toString() should return string but returns string|false

Tags: php, types, type-hinting, phpstan

My function is `__toString`:

```
public function __toString(): string
{
    return json_encode($this->payload);
}
```

This is the error that I receive from PhpStan, blocking me from making a commit:

> Method App\DTO\GenericMessageDTO::__toString() should return string but returns string|false.

I tried with exception but is not compatible with my php 7.2 **it says Throwing an exception from ''__toString'' is only possible since PHP 7.4**

```
public function __toString(): string
{
    if ($this->payload === false) {
        throw new \Exception("No payload");
    }
    return json_encode($this->payload);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can maybe return an empty string ? It is not ideal as you need to check yourself if something went wrong at each (implicit) call, but it seems there is no better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from `json_encode` directly, and this legacy function has a return type of `string|false`, as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). If for any reason it fails to encode `$payload`, it will return `false` instead of a string.

And as you discovered, throwing an exception in `__toString()` is not accepted unless you upgrade to  7.4  (the sooner the better! :))

This would be  a simple way to fix your `toString()` declaration, to make sure you **always** return a string.

```
public function __toString(): string
{
    return json_encode($this->payload) ?: '';
}
```